# How to construct valid rdf/xml?

Tags: validation, rdf

I have a valid rdf/xml file and I have to put it in another tag, so on the first level to have only one tag element.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:rtc_cm="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/rtc/cm/1.0/"
    xmlns:oslc="http://open-services.net/ns/core#" >
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://10.0.2.79:9443/ccm/oslc/types/_tsVvMWWwEeWQIIEAtKgWEg/com.ibm.team.apt.workItemType.story">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/rtc/cm/1.0/Type"/>
    <rtc_cm:projectArea rdf:resource="https://10.0.2.79:9443/ccm/oslc/projectareas/_tsVvMWWwEeWQIIEAtKgWEg"/>
    <rtc_cm:category rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">com.ibm.team.workitem.workItemType.story</rtc_cm:category>
    <rtc_cm:iconUrl rdf:resource="https://10.0.2.79:9443/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.model.IImageContentService/processattachment/_tsVvMWWwEeWQIIEAtKgWEg/workitemtype/story.gif"/>
    <dcterms:title rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Story</dcterms:title>
    <dcterms:identifier rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">com.ibm.team.apt.workItemType.story</dcterms:identifier>
  </rdf:Description>
...
   <rdf:Description ...2>
   </rdf:Description ...2>
    </rdf:RDF>
```

Here as you see there are can be more than one Description elements.
I want to put all of them in one tag. How to do that? If I try:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:rtc_cm="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/rtc/cm/1.0/"
    xmlns:oslc="http://open-services.net/ns/core#" >
<rdf:MyTag rdf:about="https://10.0.2.79:9443/ccm/oslc/types/_tsVvMWWwEeWQIIEAtKgWEg/com.ibm.team.apt.workItemType.story">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://10.0.2.79:9443/ccm/oslc/types/_tsVvMWWwEeWQIIEAtKgWEg/com.ibm.team.apt.workItemType.story">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/rtc/cm/1.0/Type"/>
    <rtc_cm:projectArea rdf:resource="https://10.0.2.79:9443/ccm/oslc/projectareas/_tsVvMWWwEeWQIIEAtKgWEg"/>
    <rtc_cm:category rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">com.ibm.team.workitem.workItemType.story</rtc_cm:category>
    <rtc_cm:iconUrl rdf:resource="https://10.0.2.79:9443/ccm/service/com.ibm.team.workitem.common.internal.model.IImageContentService/processattachment/_tsVvMWWwEeWQIIEAtKgWEg/workitemtype/story.gif"/>
    <dcterms:title rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Story</dcterms:title>
    <dcterms:identifier rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">com.ibm.team.apt.workItemType.story</dcterms:identifier>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:MyTag>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I added MyTag, but an error apperas:

```xml
Error: {E205} rdf:Description is not allowed as an element tag here.[Line = 9, Column = 128]
Error: {E201} rdf:about not allowed as attribute here.[Line = 9, Column = 128]
Error: {E201} rdf:resource not allowed as attribute here.[Line = 10, Column = 79]
Error: {E201} Multiple children of property element[Line = 11, Column = 110]
Error: {E201} rdf:resource not allowed as attribute here.[Line = 11, Column = 110]
......

Warning: {W113} rdf:MyTag is not a recognized RDF property or type.[Line = 8, Column = 122]
```

I use for validation:
http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/

I do something stupid I thing. Probably in the http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/ are defined other tags than MyProp, but if I open that link I can not see the valid tags? How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobV indicated, technically it's possible to do this, but it is fundamentally problematic that the tool you're using requires this, and likely indicates deeper problems - so I doubt that fixing this will help you all that much: any fix that results in syntactically legal RDF/XML is likely to still be impossible to process by this tool.

However, here goes: in RDF/XML, each `Description` element captures the description (in terms of its properties) for a particular resource. The resource described is the one identified in the `rdf:about` attribute.

So:

```xml
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person1">
          <rdfs:label>John</rdfs:label>
   </rdf:Description>
```

is a description of a single resource `http://example.org/person1`, and its property `rdfs:label`, which has the value "John". In RDF-terms: we have defined a single *triple* (or *statement*):

```
<http://example.org/person1> rdfs:label "John" .
```

Your RDF file contains more than one description. Although you haven't shown the `rdf:about` attributes of any of the other `Description` elemements, I assume they are different - which means they are descriptions of *different things* :

```xml
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person1">
          <rdfs:label>John</rdfs:label>
   </rdf:Description>
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person2">
          <rdfs:label>Paul</rdfs:label>
   </rdf:Description>
```

which corresponds to the following RDF statements:

```
<http://example.org/person1> rdfs:label "John" .
<http://example.org/person2> rdfs:label "Paul" .
```

We could of course put everything in a single `Description` element, but then what should the value of its `rdf:about` attribute become? If we picked one at random we'd get something like this:

```xml
   <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person1">
          <rdfs:label>John</rdfs:label>
          <rdfs:label>Paul</rdfs:label>
   </rdf:Description>
```

While doing this leads to syntactically correct RDF/XML, it corresponds to the following RDF model:

```
<http://example.org/person1> rdfs:label "John" .
<http://example.org/person1> rdfs:label "Paul" .
```

This is clearly undesirable, since it is factually wrong (there is not just one person called both "John" and "Paul", there's two separate persons, one named "John", the other named "Paul"). In other words, it fixes the syntax problem, but messes up the actual *meaning* of your data.

The first element underneath the `rdf:RDF` element in RDF/XML is expected to be either a `rdf:Description` element, or a different element which indicates a class name (this is a shorthand for writing down a description of a resource and assigning it a class by adding a property). Let's forget about that shorthand notation for a bit and just focus on `rdf:Description`. Clearly, we can't just have something like this:

```xml
  <rdf:Description> 
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person1">
          <rdfs:label>John</rdfs:label>
     </rdf:Description>
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person2">
          <rdfs:label>Paul</rdfs:label>
     </rdf:Description>
  </rdf:Description>
```

This is syntactically invalid because an RDF processor expects the elements nested inside a description to be the *properties* of the resource - but here we just have other descriptions, which no indication as to what the actual relation between those description and the 'outer' description is. This can be fixed by further nesting each 'inner' description in a property, like so:

```xml
  <rdf:Description> 
     <ex:contains> 
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person1">
            <rdfs:label>John</rdfs:label>
        </rdf:Description>
     <ex:contains>
     <ex:contains>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person2">
            <rdfs:label>Paul</rdfs:label>
        </rdf:Description>
     <ex:contains>
  <rdf:Description>
```

This is syntactially legal (assuming you also add a namespace definition to the `rdf:RDF` element for the `ex` namespace), and preserves the meaning of your original, separate descriptions. If you want to limit the number of times you have to repeat the `ex:contains` element, you can also use an RDF Collection, like so:

```xml
  <rdf:Description> 
     <ex:contains rdf:parseType="Collection"> 
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person1">
            <rdfs:label>John</rdfs:label>
        </rdf:Description>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/person2">
            <rdfs:label>Paul</rdfs:label>
        </rdf:Description>
     <ex:contains>
  <rdf:Description>
```

As said though: while this fixes the specific problem you asked about, neither of these solution are likely to help you much further. If the tool you're using to process this data can't deal with more than one `rdf:Description`, it's unlikely to be able to process either of the above files meaningfully. And also, as soon as you use any sort of proper RDF tooling to process/edit the file, it is likely to change this surface syntax again to something with more than one description. The point is that relying on the precise syntax formatting of the RDF/XML syntax is a *Very Bad Idea*(tm).

Comment: Great !! Thanks for the deeply explanation. You made my day.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to put all of them in one tag

Why?

RDF/XML is a serialisation of a RDF Graph in XML, you are constrained by the rules of RDF/XML and you really should not care what the XML looks like.

If you are working with a system that does care then that is a **bug**/**poor design** in the system you are working with and the system should change not the RDF.  This of course assumes that your RDF/XML expresses the appropriate RDF graph that the system wishes to consume.

Any manipulation of RDF/XML (or any other RDF serialisation) should be done using an appropriate API or Toolkit that will understand and enforce the rules for you.

For anything beyond trivial examples you should really never be editing RDF by hand.

Comment: I want to change it ,because the system that reads it works in that way. It suppose that there is one root tag after the rdf:RDF, and if we have 4-5 only the first is returned. So that why I want to change my Rdf. Is it possible? TO put these Description tags in one root? Technically?

Comment: Yes technically it is possible (see http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#example2) but as I described the need to do so implies a problem in the system you are working with